# Convert string to datatime in java

Tags: java, datetime

I've spent hours trying to convert the datetime string shown below to Timestamp. I am getting the error stated below and I cannot get it to work:

```
 String str = "7/1/2015 11:36 AM"; DateTimeFormatter formatter =
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); LocalDateTime
 dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Here is the error :- Text '7/1/2015 11:36 AM' could not be parsed at index 0

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Try this:

```
String str = "07/01/2015 11:36 AM"; 
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"); 
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

your formatter was wrong , you added the second in the parse, but not in the string , it was `7/1/2015 11:36 AM` and not `7/1/2015 11:36:00 AM` and you wrote the month with only one character, but it required two.

And if you want to write the month and day without 0 use this formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
             DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Then the output is:

> 2015-07-01T11:36

Comment: Michele. Thank you .. actually the data is coming in from a csv file, so I had to change the time format to "M/d/yyy h:m a" in order to accommodate single digit date and time

Comment: You're welcome , however there is the JavaDocs I made you a little bit to see, then you can change the formatter to your liking.